# Embedding vs. Inheritance in Go

Tags: go

I'm trying to learn Go, but I keep bashing my head against some of its concepts that apply differently compared to other languages.

Suppose I have a struct

```golang
type Vehicle struct {
    Seats int
}
```

I now want another struct, which embeds `Vehicle`:

```golang
type Car struct {
    Vehicle
    Color string
}
```

As I understand it, the `Car` struct now *embeds* `Vehicle`.

Now I want to have a function that takes *any* vehicle

```golang
func getSeats(v Vehicle){
    return v.Seats
}
```

But whenever I try to pass a `Car`:

```golang
    getSeats(myCar)
```

I get the following error:
`cannot use myCar (value of type Car) as Vehicle value in argument to getSeats`
But my IDE tells me `myCar` has a `Seats` property!

From this I understand that embedding is not the same as inheriting.

My question is; Is there an equivalent to struct inheritance like c++, where a function can take a base struct, or is this something Go handles completely different? How would I implement something like this in the "Go way"?

Comment: There is no such thing as inheritance in Go. "I want to have a function that takes any vehicle." This is where your mental model goes wrong. There is only *one* type of Vehicle, because Vehicle is a concrete type, not an interface. Either call `getSeats(myCar.Vehicle)`, or make Vehicle an interface if you want polymorphism.

Comment: `Now I want to have a function that takes any vehicle` Do you really need to to begin with. The example is contrived and I find it hard to perceive the need here.

Comment: Go is unique.  The sooner you discard the notion that it acts like other programming languages you know, the faster you'll be able to wrap your head around it.   Take some time understanding the answers here, which have some great gems of knowledge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like you mentioned, Go has no inheritance in the typical sense. Embedding is really just syntactic sugar.

When embedding, you add a field to you struct with the exact same name as the type you are embedding. Any methods of the embedded struct can be called on the struct which embeds them, this does nothing more than forwarding them.

One tick is that, if the struct which embeds another already declares a method, it will be preferred over forwarding it, which allows you to sort of overwrite functions if you want to think of it like that.

As you have noticed, we can't use `Car` as a `Vehicle` even if `Car` embeds `Vehicle` since they are strictly not the same type. But any struct which embeds `Vehicle` will have all methods which were defined by `Vehicle`, thus if we define an interface which `Vehicle` implements, all types that embed `Vehicle` should also implement that interface.

For example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Seater interface {
    Seats() int
}

type Vehicle struct {
    seats int
}

func (v *Vehicle) Seats() int {
    return v.seats
}

type Car struct {
    Vehicle
    Color string
}

type Bike struct {
    Vehicle
    Flag bool
}

// A bike always has 1 seat
func (b *Bike) Seats() int {
    return 1
}

type Motorcycle struct {
    Vehicle
    Sidecar bool
}

// A motorcycle has the base amounts of seats, +1 if it has a side car
func (m *Motorcycle) Seats() int {
    return m.Vehicle.seats + 1
}

func getSeats(v Seater) int {
    return v.Seats()
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(getSeats(&Bike{
        Vehicle: Vehicle{
            seats: 2, // Set to 2 in the Vehicle
        },
        Flag: true,
    }))

    fmt.Println(getSeats(&Motorcycle{
        Vehicle: Vehicle{
            seats: 1,
        },
        Sidecar: true,
    }))

    fmt.Println(getSeats(&Car{
        Vehicle: Vehicle{
            seats: 4,
        },
        Color: "blue",
    }))
}
```

This prints:

```
1
2
4
```

In the case of `Bike` the `Bike.Seats` method is called which is why it returns `1` even when the `seats` value of its `Vehicle` is `2`.

In the case of `Motorcycle` the `Motorcycle.Seats` method is also called, but here we can access the embedded type and still use it to get a result.

In the case of `Car`, the `Vehicle.Seats` method is called since `Car` doesn't "overwrite" `Seats`.

Answer (score 2):

This is something I cared about when I started with Go. I thought using concepts from OOP languages like Java is natural way of doing things. Well its not, Go is not object oriented and it does not implement polymorphism trough inheritance. In the end, composition that Go supports takes good things from what inheritance offers and removes things that adds more overhead then effective help. Go's answer to polymorphism are interfaces. Go tries to be simple and you can usually achieve things only one obvious way. Lets say you have a Java classes like these:

```java
class Base {
    private int attribute;

    public int getAttribute() {
        return this.attribute;
    }
}

class Something extends Base {}
```

In java every object is on the heap and you have pointer to it. It can be `null` and it also means it has same size when you pass it around. This is one of the reasons why you can pass objects more freely (Whether you pass `Base` or `Something`, as long as argument type is super class, it will compile). Go is designed to manage memory more efficiently and use stack more then heap, and even heap is less fragmented. When you declare a `struct`, the size of that struct is determined by data it holds, so you cannot pass it to places where embedded structure belongs. Let's give an example:

```golang
type Base struct {
   attribute int32 
}

func (b *Base) Attribute() int32 {
    return b.attribute
}

type Something struct {
    garbage int32
    Base
}
```

While `Base` has 4 bytes, `Something` has 8, and `attribute` has different offset. If the compiler lets you pass `Something` in place of `Base`, you would access `garbage` instead of `attribute`. If you want to get this behavior you have to use interface. Luckily, all you have to declare is this:

```golang
type BaseInterface interface {
    Attribute() int32
}
```

Now that you have this interface, you can make general functions over all structs that embed Base (unless it also embeds something else that has method names `Attribute` on the same level) like this:

```golang
func DoubleOfBaseAttribute(base BaseInterface) int32 {
    return base.Attribute() * 2
}
```

This is also called Dynamic Dispatch and its what languages like C++ or Java use implicitly.